# Multiple queries using code igniter, how does it know to not mixup the where clauses

Tags: codeigniter

Below I have two queries that are working as expected. How does CodeIgniter know to not add 2 where clauses to the second query? Does it reset the query statements after $this->db->update?

```
    //Make sure customers don't belong to tier anymore
    $this->db->where('tier_id', $tier_id);
    $this->db->update('customers', array('tier_id' => NULL));

    $this->db->where('id', $tier_id);
    return $this->db->delete('price_tiers');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look in the System/database/db_active_rec.php core file, you can see (for example) the update() function

The first thing it does is calls:

```
    // Combine any cached components with the current statements
       $this->_merge_cache();
```

This is how the CRUD statements collect any "partial" where, etc clauses.

The second to last thing it does is calls:

```
     _reset_write();
```

This resets them all to empty. Then it calls the query() to send off the statement